# Not able to access APIS of Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central

Tags: php, dynamics-business-central

I have to implement the apis of Microsoft Dynamics 365 into my website but not able to access it. I have implemented authentication by using this https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client, which is working fine. Microsoft graph apis are working but I can't use Microsoft Dynamics 365.

In app also I added the permission of Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business central. With reference of this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/api-reference/v1.0/api/dynamics_companies_get to fetch company detail I tried following:

**Endpoint**

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/production/abc.onmicrosoft.com/api/v1.0/companies
Method - Get
```

With token that I got from authentication

I am getting this error -

```
    {
     "error": {
        "code": "RequestDataInvalid",
        "message": "Request data is invalid."
     }
    }
```

However, I can access Microsoft graph apis.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

I two struggled with this.

Seams that tenantId and environment is mixed up in their demo.

This worked for me:
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{tenantid}/{environment}/api/v1.0/companies

EX
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/55555555-5555-5555-5555-555555555555/production/api/v1.0/companies